# How to use for-loop to feed array element into postgresql query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, for-loop, postgresql-9.6

I would like to loop my query based on each element of an array.
And I just want one result from each element out of the query.

Something like this:

```
array = ['a', 'b', 'c']

For i in array LOOP

SELECT *
FROM table_xyz
WHERE id = i
LIMIT 1

END LOOP;
```

So that I will have a table result like this:

```
id     | value
-------+--------
a      |  123
b      |  456
c      |  789
```

Comment: A cursor is more often than not a bad choice. It's a slow row-by-row processing whereas relational databases are optimized against doing set based operations.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the comments, I am kinda new to sql stuff. I am still trying to figuring those concepts here.

Answer (score 1):

Why not get the results all at once:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM table_xyz
    WHERE id in ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Comment: Thanks. Because I have thousands of id, and there are a lot of data from each id in the table. So it will cost a lot of time in the query and a lot of work to filter the result.

Comment: Well running thousands of separate queries will cost quite a bit of time as well. Without more understanding of the actual application, it's hard to make a suggestion, but you might want to consider putting your thousands of ids in a table (even a temporary table) and perform a `JOIN` with that table. getting a single results set is generally preferable to running thousands of queries.

Comment: make sense, I will give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: Or use the array directly: `where id = any(array_variable)`